# What is the best way to update promise object and to announce it?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is promise is the right pattern for object that may change couple of time?
What is the best way to update promise object and to announce it (resolve it again? In this case, will the relevant callback (done/then) will run again?) ?

Comment: This is not opinion based, just because something has "what is the best way" in it doesn't automagically make it opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

Promises are *immutable* once resolved (`then` will always yield the same value), they cannot be 'updated'. Based on your question it sounds like you want an [*observable*](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS).

Comment: It might be beneficial to link to the ["official" observable](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-observable) instead.

Comment: You are correct, I just tend to reach for Rx first because its probably the most familiar. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Promises can be resolved once. If you want to watch for a change, you can go for either Observable or some kind of pub-sub pattern.